# Getting the relative path from current directory to a folder given as argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell, relative-path

To be more specific:
Let's say current directory is ~/Bash/ and which contains ~/Bash/test/

```
myscrip.sh .
```

should get the output "Generating Bash.html"

```
myscrip.sh ../Bash/test
```

or

```
myscrip.sh test/
```

both should get "Generating ./test.html"

This is my attempt at getting relative path but it's my first script,
so i'm not very resourceful yet.

```
#! /bin/bash 

[ $# -ne 1 ] \
  && echo -e " Script usage: \n\t `basename $0` <folder>" \
  && exit 1

[ -d "$1" ] || { echo "Folder doesn't exist" && exit 2; }

folder=`find -maxdepth 1 -name "${1%/}"`
echo -e "Generating $folder.html"
```

Comment: I've just realized that a correct output for the first example would be
 
    Generating ..html
which i'd like to avoid

Comment: Also, there is a way in bash to set de default directory where the script navigates when cd is called. It would be useful for my script, but i don't remember how to do it.

Comment: You can set the `HOME` environment variable to change where `cd` takes you, but doing so is not in very good style. Doing it changes the behavior of more than just `cd`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
folder=`find -maxdepth 1 -name "${1%/}"`
```

use

```
folder=$(basename "$(realpath -s "$1")")
```

The rest looks okay.

- `realpath` (part of the GNU coreutils) will give you the canonicalized version of the path it is given as an argument. `realpath .` will print the same as `pwd`, `realpath ../Bash/test` will give you `/home/user/Bash/test` and so forth. The `-s` argument prevents resolution of symlinks.
- `basename` isolates the innermost directory name from it, which is the one you wanted.
- `$()` does command substitution; it is similar to backticks but more easily nested.

One caveat: You will want to check for `"$1" == "/"`, where this logic ultimately breaks down (`folder` becomes `/`, and without special handling, you'd attempt to write to `/.html`). Whether you want to forbid it or do something special for it is a design question you'll have to answer yourself.

Comment: Realpath wasn't recognized. I resorted to combine cd and $PWD (less elegant but it works). I didn't find the special (non-$HOME) var to set starting directory, so i just made one myself initializing it from $PWD).

I'll update with my code as soon as i got the time.

Comment: Hmm...realpath has been in the coreutils since early 2012 (I just looked that up), so if you're using an older Linux, perhaps it's not there yet. I'm a bit surprised it's that new, actually; BSD had it since forever. Abusing `readlink` is not an option, I suppose, since you don't want to resolve symlinks.